# GCC 'constructor' attribute - only one per translation unit?

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

I have two functions with the 'constructor' attribute in a single .c file, but only the first one gets actually called before main(), the second one is silently ignored. Is it a normal behaviour? I couldn't find any documentation on the subject

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Why bother? Add another one, let it call those two others, and remove the `constructor` attribute form the latter.

Comment: @tristan: Although mostly code is necessary to clarify the OP's question, I doubt it is in this case.